# How to have constant distance between the beginning of a paragraph and the beginning of the previous one?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I have paragraphs that can be one or two lines long. I want the distance between the beginnings of two consecutive paragraphs A and B to be constant. How can I achieve that?

Basically, if A has one line only, I would like to have like a "ghost blank line" so the beginning of B is at a distance from the beginning of A which is equal to the distance you would have if A had two lines (I don't want to manually add vertical spaces to paragraphs that happen to have one line)

Edit:

Here is a MWE (note I am using tabular instead of paragraph as suggested in the comments)

I want these two tikz text nodes to have their lines starting at the same height. I don't worry to much about the mess that the argument of `\content` is because I am going to generate it programatically. (the use of tikz text nodes is neccesary. The use of tabularx is not necessary but the format should match what I have below, i.e., numbers on the left and the rest of the paragrah aligned to the left (T of This on top of the w of will) )

Bonus points for generating a warning or error if I add a paragraph that is three lines long or more by accident.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7} 
\usepackage{tabularx}  

\newcommand{\content}[1]{
    \node[text width=5cm]  {
        \scriptsize 
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r @{} X @{}} 
            #1
        \end{tabularx}
    };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \content{ \textbf{1. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{2. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{3. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{4. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{5. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{6. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{7. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{8. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{9. } & \textbf{One line} \\ \textbf{10. } & \textbf{One line}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \content{ \textbf{1. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{2. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{3. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{4. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{5. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{6. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{7. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{8. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{9. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines} \\ \textbf{10. } & \textbf{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds like something for which paragraphs might not be best suited; a tabular-like construction or `minipage`s might be better. However, it would be easier to answer if you explained precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: It would be nice for you to prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) explaining exactly what you need. As it is now, the question is not detailed enough. For example, what should happen if you have a page break between lines in a paragraph with two lines? Or if you have a tall math formula in one line?

Comment: @Rmano The context is a bit random and lengthy. Basically I'm doing some cards with tikz and I have some paragraphs with text in them. The text is a tikz text node and I could hardcode different text nodes to have everything start at the same height for different cards, but it is more convenient if it is just one node because some other cards will be different. I want these two cards to have paragraphs starting at the same height https://imgur.com/a/JlmJVWc Floating environments like tabular are not allowed within tikz text nodes

Comment: @Damaru you can't use a float like a `table` in a tikz node (notice that this is all new info that should be in the question!) , but you definitely can use a `tabular`! Althoug your example can be coded with a `enumerate` of `minipages`... please add a minimal example.

Comment: @Rmano ah, silly me, ofc I can use tabular. Still, I don't know how to fix row height equal to the height of a paragraph with two lines. I added a MWE. Sorry for adding a mess in the argument of \content.

Comment: Do you see no contradiction between "… the beginnings of two consecutive paragraphs A and B to be constant" and varying that same distance depending on how many lines A has?

Can you clarify which you really want?

Comment: Alternatively, using an environ \BODY one could first determine the maximum height needed, then generate the text using this height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a completely different idea: given that you are in a `tikzpicture`, use `\path` movements...

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\overfullrule=5pt
\newcommand{\oneline}{One line of text}
\newcommand{\twolines}{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines}
\newcommand{\slap}[2]{%
    \path (start) node[anchor=base west, text width=0.5cm, 
          font=\scriptsize\bfseries, inner xsep=0.2cm, align=right](tmp){#1}
    (tmp.base east) node[anchor=base west, text width=4.8cm, align=left,
          font=\scriptsize](tmp){#2.};
    \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=-0.7cm]start);
}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
        \slap{1}{\oneline}
        \slap{2}{\twolines}
        \slap{3}{\twolines}
        \slap{4}{\oneline}
        \slap{5}{\oneline}
        \slap{6}{\oneline}
        \slap{7}{\oneline}
        \slap{8}{\oneline}
        \slap{9}{\oneline}
        \slap{10}{\oneline}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
        \slap{1}{\twolines}
        \slap{2}{\twolines}
        \slap{3}{\twolines}
        \slap{4}{\twolines}
        \slap{5}{\twolines}
        \slap{6}{\oneline}
        \slap{7}{\oneline}
        \slap{8}{\twolines{} And if I wrote too much, it'll overlap: \twolines}
        \slap{9}{\oneline}
        \slap{10}{\oneline}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the extra point, you can measure if the box is bigger than the movement and issue an error in that case:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myerror}{%
    \@latex@error
      {Too many lines here}% Error message
      {The box is overlapping with the previous one}% Help text
}
\makeatother

\overfullrule=5pt
\newcommand{\oneline}{One line of text}
\newcommand{\twolines}{This text contains two lines, I will never write three lines}
\newcommand{\slap}[2]{%
    \path (start) node[anchor=base west, text width=0.5cm, font=\scriptsize\bfseries, inner xsep=0.2cm, align=right](tmp){#1.}
    (tmp.base east)
    node[anchor=base west, text width=4.8cm, align=left, font=\scriptsize](tmp){#2.};
    \coordinate (start) at ([yshift=-0.7cm]start);
    % let's calculate the vertical distance between (tmp.south) and (start)
    \path  let \p1=(start),\p2=(tmp.south),\n1={\y1-\y2} in \pgfextra{\xdef\tmpp{\n1}};
    % you may need to tweak the "0pt" here 
    \ifdim\tmpp>0pt\myerror\fi
}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
        \slap{1}{\oneline}
        \slap{2}{\twolines}
        \slap{3}{\twolines}
        \slap{4}{\oneline}
        \slap{5}{\oneline}
        \slap{6}{\oneline}
        \slap{7}{\oneline}
        \slap{8}{\oneline}
        \slap{9}{\oneline}
        \slap{10}{\oneline}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \coordinate (start) at (0,0);
        \slap{1}{\twolines}
        \slap{2}{\twolines}
        \slap{3}{\twolines}
        \slap{4}{\twolines}
        \slap{5}{\twolines}
        \slap{6}{\oneline}
        \slap{7}{\oneline}
        \slap{8}{\twolines{} And if I wrote too much, it'll overlap: \twolines}% error here
        \slap{9}{\oneline}
        \slap{10}{\oneline}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

this will generate an error for the overlength line:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many lines here.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.50 ... wrote too much, it'll overlap: \twolines}
                                                  % error here
?
```

Comment: Nice. Thx. Any idea about how to solve the bonus question? (i.e., knowing when you typed more than two lines accidentallly)

Comment: What happens here is that you have the "overlong" text superimposed (see entry 8 on the right column). In principle should be possible to add an error by comparing `(tmp.south)` with `(start)` at the end of the macro... hmmm...

Comment: @Damaru done! you probably must tweak a bit the `>0pt`, but more or less it works...

Comment: wow, awesome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{twolines}
{\noindent
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}}
{\strut\end{minipage}\egroup%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0>2\baselineskip 
  \textcolor{red}{ERROR: $>$2 lines\\Text Discarded}\else
  \setbox2=\vbox{\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][2\baselineskip][t]{\textwidth}
  \box0
  \end{minipage}}%
\box2\fi}
\begin{document}
Indents and margins\\are here

\begin{twolines}
1. This is a test
\end{twolines}

\begin{twolines}
2. This is a test\\and more of a test
\end{twolines}

\begin{twolines}
3. This is a test\\and more of a test\\and yet again
\end{twolines}

Next
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one still wanted to present the overlong material, there is this alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{twolines}
{\noindent
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}}
{\strut\end{minipage}\egroup%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0>2\baselineskip 
  \textcolor{red}{WARNING: What follows is $>$2 lines}\\\box0\else
  \setbox2=\vbox{\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][2\baselineskip][t]{\textwidth}
  \box0
  \end{minipage}}%
  \box2\fi
}
\begin{document}
Indents and margins\\are here

\begin{twolines}
1. This is a test
\end{twolines}

\begin{twolines}
2. This is a test\\and more of a test
\end{twolines}

\begin{twolines}
3. This is a test\\and more of a test\\and yet again
\end{twolines}

Next
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can count how many lines the previous paragraph consists of, using the `\prevgraf` primitive.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\newenvironment{twolines}
 {\par}
 {\par\vspace{\numexpr2-\prevgraf\relax\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{twolines}
1. This has one line
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
2. This has one line
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
3. This has two lines, not more than two line, really no more than that
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
4. This has two lines, not more than two line, really no more than that
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
5. This has one line
\end{twolines}

\newpage % just to show what happens

\begin{twolines}
6. This has two lines, not more than two line, really no more than that
but this actually has more than two lines, oops
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
7. This has one line
\end{twolines}
\begin{twolines}
8. This has two lines, not more than two line, really no more than that
\end{twolines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a warning when the paragraph has more than two lines, this modified version

```
\newenvironment{twolines}
 {\par}
 {\par\ifnum\prevgraf>2 \typeout{WARNING! More than two lines on line \the\inputlineno!}\fi
  \vspace{\numexpr2-\prevgraf\relax\baselineskip}}
```

will log

```
WARNING! More than two lines on line 31!
```